# DocumentDB REST API: PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to insert a JSON document into DocumentDB via REST, using PHP (which lacks an official API wrapper). Now, it seems that a partition key has become mandatory for any collection in DocumentDB, but i cannot find the REST API documented.

I get the following error in return:

```
PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header
```

The JSON document I'm trying to insert looks as follows:

```
{ id:"1", ... "domain":"domain.com" }
```

In Azure, I have defined the collection with the following partition key:

```
/domain
```

And when sending the REST request, I send along the following header:

```
x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey: [ "domain" ]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You would need to specify the partition key value and not the attribute i.e. you would write `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey: [ "domain.com" ]`. Please try with this.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot! (Please add your reply as an answer - not comment - so I can set accepted/solved)

Comment: Clarification: Partition keys are required for *partitioned collections*, not for single-partition collections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey` value you would need to specify the partition key value (`"domain.com"`) and not the partition key attribute (`"domain"`).

`x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey: [ "domain.com" ]`

Once you do this, documents matching this partition key value will be returned.